# Numpy: How can I add (4, ) array and (9, 9) array to (9, 9, 4) array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 10, 11, 1])
 
# OUT:
# array([ 0, 10, 11,  1])
 
b = np.arange(81).reshape(9, 9)
# OUT:
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
#       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
#       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
#       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
#       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
#       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
#       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
#       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]])
```

I want each item of b-array add to a-array, and get the result like, just like a simple loop can do:

```
result = list()

for row in b:
    ls = list()
    
    for i in row:
        c = a + i
        ls.append(c)

    result.append(ls)
np.array(result)
```

Loop is not efficient enough, is there any way that I can use the Numpy broadcast rule to get this result?(Numpy array)

Comment: `np.add.outer(b,a)` gives you the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of "general" way to do this is by indexing with `None`. If you index an array with `None`, it creates a new axis and broadcasts the array along that axis.

So if you have `a.shape = (4,)` and `b.shape = (9,9)`, you can add like this:

```
a[:,None,None] + b[None,:,:]
```

The `:` in the index for `a` is the only axis of `a`, which has size 4. The remaining two axes, the `None,None`, are new axes that get broadcast to match `b`.

The `:,:` indexes in the index for `b` are the axes in the array, with shape `(9,9)`. The `None` is a new axis, broadcast to match `a`.

There may be a shorter way to write this but I can't be bothered to remember how the rules for implicit broadcasting works, so I just make it explicit.

You can also use `numpy.newaxis` if that is clearer, but it has the same effect.

Comment: You can also use `np.newaxis` in place of `None` to be more explicit. But `np.newaxis` is simply mapped to `None`.